# If $(D_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is such that $2014 = \frac {2013^{D^{31}_n +1} } {2013^{D^{31}_{n+1}}-2014^{0.1}},$ then $\lim(D_n) < \pm \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence $(D_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that  $2014 = \frac {2013^{D^{31}_n +1} }  {2013^{D^{31}_{n+1}}-2014^{0.1}}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$ How do I show that $\lim(D_n) < \pm \infty ?$

Here is my attempt:

Suppose $  \lim_{n \to \infty} D_n \  \text{does not exist.}$

Since $\ 2014=\frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{({D^{31}_n +1})\ln(2013)} }{  \lim_{n \to \infty} 2013^{D^{31}_{n+1}}-2014^{0.1}}, \text {so} \ \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{({D^{31}_n +1})\ln(2013)} \leq \pm \infty. $ I'm trying to show that $\lim(D_n) \leq  \pm \infty.$ How do I continue from here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From the given equality we have
$$2014( 2013^{D_{n+1}^{31}}-1)=2013(2013^{D_{n}^{31}}-1)$$
so the sequence
$$u_n=2013^{D_{n}^{31}}-1$$
is geometric with ratio $q=\frac{2013}{2014}<1$ hence convergent to $0$ so it's easy to see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} D_n=0$$

Comment: We have $\lim 2013^{D_n^{31}}=1$ so apply the $\log$ function and the $\sqrt[31]{.}$ function you find the limit